# Prometheus - Match all metrics but one

Tags: prometheus

How can I match all Prometheus metrics except some?

E.g: `{__name__!~"metric_to_discard"}`

Does not work, it returns `Error executing query: parse error at char 35: vector selector must contain at least one non-empty matcher`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some kind of safety mechanism to avoid heavy load on Prometheus by accidentally using too wide selectors. Usually you shouldn't have a need for such a query that matches (almost) every metric with all label dimensions.

There is [some hacky solution to workaround this safety check](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2162) by adding another dimension with a `..*` or `.+` match-all selector. (The safety check also forbids using `.*`)

```
{job=~"..*", __name__!~"metric_to_discard"}
```

**Caution: Be aware that this query will probably hit your Prometheus instance pretty hard and this should not be used on a production system.**

As already said, there is probably a better way to get the result you like without querying for almost each and every metric. Please consider posting a new question describing what result you really want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, that works. The use case is to use the Prometheus tsdb API to delete all metrics but only a few. This way we can have long-term metrics that are used for reporting and dispose all others to free up disk space.

Comment: If you don't need all label dimensions but only the metrics names, you could probably also use a direct api call to list all label values of the `__name__` dimension by accessing `http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/label/__name__/values` and then manually removing the `metric_to_discard`

Comment: Thanks for this. I used a slightly different variant of this one when I wanted to federate everything except for the job="prometheus" metrics:
`{job=~".+", job!="prometheus"}`

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus supports `{__name__!=""}` query, which returns all the time series. E.g. this query is equivalent to the following SQL query: `SELECT * FROM metrics` (note that this query may crash Prometheus if Prometheus contains many time series). Prometheus allows using multiple filters against the same label (including `__name__` label, which maps to metric name). So the following query would return all the time series except the `metric_to_discard` metric:

```
{__name__!="",__name__!~"metric_to_discard"}
```

P.S. The `__name__!=""` hack isn't needed in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - the Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. It just returns the expected results from `{__name__!~"metric_to_discard"}` query.