# How to query all time series that have certain label value in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm storing metrics in Prometheus and some metrics belong to certain events and have an `event_id` label. Every event is unique and only happens once so it will have some start time, end time, and duration.

I need to query chosen metrics' values (let's name them `metric1` and `metric2`) for chosen `event_id` without knowing when the event started and ended but knowing that it happened. I also need to set the time step (or frequency) of the samples. Let's say I only need to know metrics' values for every 10 seconds and not every single value that was recorded.

What PromQL query will let me accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839246/prometheus-match-all-metrics-but-one) you will see that the problem you're facing is similar. In prometheus you can use:

```
{event_id="ID", __name__=~"metric.*"} [1d]
```

Maybe you can use the [alert manager](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/), and set the rules (find the right trigger) to alert any time an eventID happens:

```
name: Event 
expr: node_load5 > 2 #find the right trigger
for: 2m
labels:
  eventID: {{eventID}} #use static or generate from time or sth
  startTime: {{startTime}}
  endTime: {{endTime}}
  severity: minor
annotations:
  summary: High load
```

Comment: As far as I know the `[1d]` notation means time duration for which every sample will be fetched. But how can I specify frequency so that not every sample gets fetched but one sample for every minute or every 5 minutes or every 30 minutes etc?

Comment: Maybe using some [aggregattion-over-time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) or [aggregation operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators)

Comment: Try sending the following query to [/api/v1query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries): `metric[1d:5m]` - it will return a single sample per each 5 minutes for the last day.